# Simple jQuery "<script defer" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagespeed, deferred-loading

I'm trying to defer a very simple jQuery test, in order to optimize the speed of my website:

This is the jQuery test:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Defer</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$("#jquerytext").html("Hello World by JQuery");});</script>
  Hello World by HTML
  <div id="jquerytext"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works correctly. However, if I change the call to the jQuery libraries:

```
<script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it won't work.

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Getting any errors in the console? This seems very related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722688/how-to-use-defer-async-attributes-in-script-tag-properly

Comment: Since jQuery was not loaded at the time of calling, than you **cannot use** jQuery methods/events as [ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), but some vanilla alternatives as `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ ... });` Other solution would be to defer your custom script, too.

Comment: It's because defer loads after html is parsed and loaded. but you try to run jquery before defer. Thats the reason it doesnt work. Basically your page now runs jquery first then import.

Answer (score 0):

As rightly pointed in the nice comments, it should have used 'window.onload' event, because it will fire after all page is loaded including deferred scripts.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Defer</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function() {
      $(document).ready(function(){$("#jquerytext").html("Hello World by JQuery");});
     };
  </script>
  Hello World by HTML
  <div id="jquerytext"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need the `$(document).ready` then... it will likely fire before `onload` on a larger page (this was always the case in earlier versions) so your code won't be executed.

Comment: By the way, since the question has the pagespeed tag - any inline script would best be pasted just before the closing body tag so it doesn't delay page rendering.